# Reverse a string pattern in java

Tags: java, string

I have this input `String input = "TOM DICK HARRY";`, I want output as `"HARRY DICK TOM"`

I have tried this (which I think is not an optimal way of doing)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "TOM DICK HARRY";

    String inputArr [] = input.split(" ");

    for (int i = inputArr.length; i >0; i--) {
        System.out.print(inputArr[i-1]+" ");    
    }

}
```

Is there any built in method to do this?

Comment: Unless you're doing this for an incredibly long string, what you have here is probably a good enough way of doing this.

Comment: What you have is fine. Why do you think it's not? In what way isn't it "optimum"?

Comment: One can also use `ArrayUtils.reverse(inputArr);
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputArr));` but then it would print square brackets in console like this: `[HARRY, DICK, TOM]`. So I found one more way not doing it optimum way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only vanilla Java 8:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "TOM DICK HARRY";

    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(input.split(" "));
    Collections.reverse(list);
    System.out.println(list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
}
```

It isn't necessarily "better" than your solution, but it uses standard API, which is what you seem to be after.

Answer (score 0):

Using Guava you can do:

```
Joiner.on(' ').join(Lists.reverse(Splitter.on(' ').splitToList("TOM DICK HARRY")));
```